# Add carriage return to output of `tail` while using `grep`

Tags: command-line, grep, tail

I'm looking to refactor the following command:

```
tail -f production.log |
    grep -e "Processing " -e "compatible;" -e "Completed in " -e
```

This is the output of the command:

> Processing BasketController#cross_sell_product (for 85.189.237.x at 2011-08-03 12:46:07) [POST]
>   "RequestLog","2011-08-03 12:46:07","12595","www.website.com","/basket/cross_sell_product/113","85.189.237.x","Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
>   Completed in 0.07853 (12 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.01402 (17%) | DB: 0.01439 (18%) | 200 OK [https://www.website.com/basket/cross_sell_product/113]

This is great and exactly what I want however I'd like to see is a carridge return or two afterwards so I can study the logs as blocks.

I tried to add `\n` to the end however this didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean a newline after **each** match, or after the whole result?

Comment: Carriage return is "\r".  You want them where/after what exactly?  Do you want to have a few blank lines between every line of output?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want a few blank lines between every line of output?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you want, but awk can probably do it easily. To add an extra newline after each matching line:

```
tail -f production.log |
awk '/Processing|compatible;|Completed in / {print; print ""}'
```

To add a newline between all blocks of non-consecutive matching lines:

```
tail -f production.log |
awk '
/Processing|compatible;|Completed in / {
    if (NR == n+1) print "";
    n = NR;
    print;
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` will filter out empty lines since they don't match any pattern.
In the case empty line separators appear in the original file you can let them pass through, adding `-e "^$"`.

If those empty lines are not present in the original file, you'll have to add them.
This is an example of how to do it:

```
 tail -f production.log | grep -e … | sed 's/\(^Processing \)/\n\1/'
```

**Edit:** if you want an empty line after *every* other line use `sed 's/$/\n/'` instead. And of course you can add as many `\n` as you like.